# How to test XElement's child element's attributes, values by using Fluent Assertions?

Tags: fluent-assertions

Let's say I have an `XElement` object, which represents Xml like

```
<modification name="givenName" operation="add" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:DSML:2:0:core">
    <value>Changed name</value>
    <child id="abc">Some dummy value</child>
</modification>
```

How can I test The `<value>` element's value is "Changed name", and `<child>` element has attribute `id` "abc", and value "Some dummy value"?

Answer (score 1):

```
element.Should().HaveElement("value").Which.Should().HaveValue("Changed name");
element.Should().HaveElement("child").Which.Should().HaveAttribute("id", "abc").And.HaveValue("Some dummy value");
```